How to test the stored procedure with varray as input and SYS_REFCURSOR as output parameter?
I am creating an oracle stored procedure to fetch records from 'configurations' table.
This stored procedure accepts an input parameter of type 'varray' because we want to fetch records for multiple 'configcategories' at once.
Also, there is an out parameter of type 'SYS_REFCURSOR' as well.
With below test script I am able to pass inputs to stored procedure but not able to print the output.
Can you please help to extract values from 'SYS_REFCURSOR' and print them on sqldeveloper console.
Finally, this stored procedure will be invoked by application written in NodeJS.
Stored Procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE configcategoryarr IS
    VARRAY(256) OF VARCHAR2(256);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_configurations (
    t_configcategory  IN   configcategoryarr,
    c_configurations  OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
    IF t_configcategory.count > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN t_configcategory.first..t_configcategory.last LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(t_configcategory(i));
            OPEN c_configurations FOR SELECT
                                          configcategory,
                                          configid,
                                          configlabel,
                                          configvalue,
                                          configenabled
                                      FROM
                                          configurations
                                      WHERE
                                          configcategory = t_configcategory(i);

        END LOOP;

    END IF;
END get_configurations;
/

Stored Procedure Test Script:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    t_cca             configcategoryarr;
    l_cursor          SYS_REFCURSOR;
    l_configcategory  configurations.configcategory%TYPE;
    l_configid        configurations.configid%TYPE;
    l_configlabel     configurations.configlabel%TYPE;
    l_configvalue     configurations.configvalue%TYPE;
    l_configenabled   configurations.configenabled%TYPE;
BEGIN
    t_cca := configcategoryarr();
    t_cca.extend(10);
    t_cca(1) := 'Department';
    t_cca(2) := 'OU';
    get_configurations(t_configcategory => t_cca, c_configurations => l_cursor);
    LOOP
        FETCH l_cursor INTO
            l_configcategory,
            l_configid,
            l_configlabel,
            l_configvalue,
            l_configenabled;
        EXIT WHEN l_cursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_configcategory
                             || '_'
                             || l_configid
                             || '_'
                             || l_configlabel
                             || '_'
                             || l_configvalue
                             || '_'
                             || l_configenabled);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/

Output:
Department
OU


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


You could also view the results like this.

Why do you run the query for each value? You can do it much more efficient like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE configcategoryarr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_configurations (
    t_configcategory  IN   configcategoryarr,
    c_configurations  OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN

   OPEN c_configurations FOR 
   SELECT
      configcategory,
      configid,
      configlabel,
      configvalue,
      configenabled
   FROM configurations
   WHERE configcategory MEMBER OF t_configcategory;

END get_configurations;


It isn't just more efficient; in the OP's code the cursor is re-opened each time round the loop, so it will only have results matching the last element in the array...

Your procedure will only return results matching the last element in the input array, because you re-open the cursor for each value - it's a new cursor, not a cumulative result set.
You would then expect to only see the results for 'OU', but the last cursor is empty, even though - presumably - you expect to see data for that value at least.
That's because your test code does this:
    t_cca := configcategoryarr();
    t_cca.extend(10);
    t_cca(1) := 'Department';
    t_cca(2) := 'OU';

You are creating an array with ten elements, but only populating the first two. The other eight still exist, they are just null. So when you loop over that collection in your procedure you open a cursor for 'Department', then throw that away and open a new cursor for 'OU', then you throw that away, and open a new cursor for null - which will always get no results; and then repeat that seven more times. So the final open of the cursor will be for null, with no results. You can see that by just looping locally:
DECLARE
    t_configcategory configcategoryarr;
BEGIN
    t_configcategory := configcategoryarr();
    t_configcategory.extend(10);
    t_configcategory(1) := 'Department';
    t_configcategory(2) := 'OU';

    dbms_output.put_line(t_configcategory.count);
    IF t_configcategory.count > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN t_configcategory.first..t_configcategory.last LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(i || ': ' || t_configcategory(i));
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END;
/

1 rows affected

dbms_output:
10
1: Department
2: OU
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: 
9: 
10: 

fiddle
If you only extend to the actual required size, either once with extend(2) or immediately before you set each element, then it won'y have those null elements:
DECLARE
    t_configcategory configcategoryarr;
BEGIN
    t_configcategory := configcategoryarr();
    t_configcategory.extend();
    t_configcategory(1) := 'Department';
    t_configcategory.extend();
    t_configcategory(2) := 'OU';

    dbms_output.put_line(t_configcategory.count);
    IF t_configcategory.count > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN t_configcategory.first..t_configcategory.last LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(i || ': ' || t_configcategory(i));
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END;
/

1 rows affected

dbms_output:
2
1: Department
2: OU

fiddle
If you passed  that array instead you would see some output - but only for 'OU', as the cursor for 'Department' is still thrown away.
If you use @Wernfried's approach to open a single cursor for all your results, as you should, then this won't matter so much - nothing will match the null elements but you'll still have results for the non-null ones. But it would still be clearer if you only made the array as large as you need; or use a different collection type.
